# Cannot figure out what im doing wrong with exporting my results to a text file

Tags: python

my goal for this code is to generate a random set of passwords after answering a few command prompt question, to save those passwords to a text document to be viewed/edited later. Im running into an issue where the text document doesn't actually get edited and after reading through some similar questions; made some adjustments. I still need help though!

```
for password in passwords:
with open('SavedPasswords.rtf' , 'a') as f:

#the following loops create the password(s) and print them to console

if special_chars == "YES" :
    for pwd in range(amount):
        passwords = ''
        for c in range(length):
            passwords += random.choice(chars)
        print(passwords)
        f.write(passwords)

elif special_chars == "NO" :
    for pwd in range(amount):
        passwords = ''
        for c in range(length):
            passwords += random.choice(chars2)
        print(passwords)
        f.write(passwords)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. I don't understand what exactly is the question you are asking, and the code doesn't work at all. Please read up [How to write good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is what work for me when re-constructing your case:

```
import random
import string    # For string module

passwords = ["", "", "", ""]
special_chars = "YES"   # Just for testing
amount = 2
length = 10

# Use the string module to get all ascii char

with_punctuation = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation
without_punctuation = string.ascii_letters

for password in passwords:
    
    with open('SavedPasswords.rtf' , 'a') as f:

        if special_chars == "YES" :
            for pwd in range(amount):
                passwords = ''
                for c in range(length):
                    passwords += random.choice(with_punctuation)
                print(passwords)
                f.write(passwords + "\n")   # Add this to separate them, I think a csv is better!

        elif special_chars == "NO" :
            for pwd in range(amount):
                passwords = ''
                for c in range(length):
                    passwords += random.choice(without_punctuation)
                print(passwords)
                f.write(passwords + "\n")
```

You didn't tell exactly what you have done so this is all I can do.